# Dart: unhandledExceptionCallback is ignored

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

Here is a very simple code that I run using command line dart to demonstrate my point:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

void isolateMain() {
  throw new Exception("ouch");
}

bool handleException(IsolateUnhandledException e) {
  print("EXCEPTION in isolate: " + e.toString());
  return true;
}

void main() {
  SendPort sendPort = spawnFunction(isolateMain, handleException);
  sendPort.call("Hello").then((e) {
    print("Main received " + e);
  });
}
```

and the output:

```
Exception: ouch
#0      isolateMain (file:///Users/salomon/Workspaces/eclipse/Deployer_Server/bin/deployer_server.dart:7:3)
```

So, turns out the unhandledExceptionCallback is never called whereas the isolate does throw an exception.

For the record :

```
> dart --version
Dart VM version: 0.5.20.4_r24275 (Fri Jun 21 05:02:50 2013) on "macos_x64"
```

So, can someone explain me what did I do wrong ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Bug report logged: http://dartbug.com/11505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you did wrong, it could be a bug. But it seems exceptions thrown in the isolate's main function aren't caught by the handler. If you change it like this:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

void isolateMain() {
  port.receive((whatever, mahPort) {
    throw new Exception("$whatever");
  });
}

bool handleException(IsolateUnhandledException e) {
  print("EXCEPTION in isolate: ${e.toString()}");
  return true;
}

void main() {
  SendPort sendPort = spawnFunction(isolateMain, handleException);
  sendPort.call("Hello").then((e) {
    print("Main received $e");
  });
}
```

... then `handleException()` will be called.

Comment: Re the String +, it's changed again: See: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/bBN-PtbNSeU/usZBhhtJJZYJ

Comment: @ChrisBuckett Funny how it can go... iirc the removal was heavily defended by the Dart team. Anyway, deleted the incorrect note. Thanks for the comment.